# Eclipse showing caution sign on the project folder icon whenever I add an external JAR file to the project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I was revisiting how to connect to a database using **JDBC** in **Eclipse**.

I created a project (**Dynamic Web Project**) and added the relevant JAR file for database connection in the external JAR files section (**Project Java Build Path --> Libraries --> Add external jars**). But still I was getting the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

I went through other posts and found a solution. Someone suggested to copy the JAR file into the **WEB-INF/lib** folder of the project. I did that and it worked.

Is adding external files like we used to on eclipse still relevant?

Also, I keep getting this caution sign on the projects (**Dynamic Web Projects**) to which I add external JARs.

[image: Screenshot]

The same thing is no problem when working on normal java projects.

My eclipse version is Luna, Java version is 8 and Apache version is 7.

Comment: Did you try refreshing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you had done allowed Eclipse to resolve the classes during development but not for deployment.

Since you're building a servlet you have to set up the project in a way that will successfully deploy as a servlet. Moving the jar to WEB-INF/lib works because all the jars in that directory will be on the default classpath for the servlet.

Comment: If the jar you need is not normally deployed by the servlet container (ie, provided by default in the servers libs) then you need to add them to your servlets WEB-INF/lib.